# Find the even extension of function $f(x) = \begin{cases} x^2-x^3, & 0 \leq x < 3 \\ 4-x , & x \geq 3 \\ \end{cases}$

Tags: algebra-precalculus, functions

Find the even extension of function
$f(x) = \begin{cases}
 x^2-x^3, & 0 \leq x < 3 \\
 4-x ,    & x \geq 3 \\
\end{cases}$

---

Definition of odd and even functions:

If $f(-x) =f(x)$ for all $x$ in the domain of $f$ the function is even

If $f(-x) =-f(x) $ for all $x$ in the domain of $f$ the function is odd

Comment: what about $g(x)=f(x)\text{ for }x\ge0,g(x)=f(-x)\text{ for }x\le0$

Comment: Hint: you want the even extension to be $x^2+x^3$ on $(-3,0)$....

Comment: What do you mean by ' Even Extension ' ?

Answer (score 2):

By an "even extension" I assume you mean an even function that that equals the given function on the domain of the given function.

The domain of your given function $f$ is the non-negative real numbers. The mother of all even functions is $|x|$, which equals $x$ on the non-negative real numbers. Using that, we get

$g(x) = \begin{cases}
  |x|^2-|x|^3, & 0 \leq |x| < 3 \\[2 ex]
  4-|x| , & |x| \geq 3
\end{cases}$

This can be simplified a bit to

$g(x) = \begin{cases}
  x^2-|x|^3, & |x| < 3 \\[2 ex]
  4-|x| , & |x| \geq 3
\end{cases}$

Or, if you want the cases to be divided by intervals,

$g(x) = \begin{cases}
  x^2+x^3, & x < -3 \\[2 ex]
  4-|x| ,  & -3\le x  \le 3 \\[2 ex]
  x^2-x^3, & 3 < x
\end{cases}$